# What is what appears to be electrical conductive tape beneath the "water-proof cap" inside the Ultegra 6600 STI assembly?

Tags: shimano

While performing some work on my Ultegra 6600 STI shifters I was curious to remove part no. 13, designated "water-proof cap" in Shimano's part fiche. To my surprise there was something that resembled conductive tape beneath it with (I think) 3 terminating metal pads. I didn't take a pic, unfortunately. Does anyone have any idea what that's for?

[image: Parts fiche]

Comment: Shimano Flight Deck?

Comment: I used to have a set of ST-6600s that had wiring for Shimano Flight Deck in them. The 'wires' are parallel conductors inside a flexible plastic tape if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flight Deck was a system where information on gear selection and cadence can be sent to a head unit to display to the rider, and combined with the wheel diameter, also speed. So electrical contacts to connect up to this. A bit superseded by GPS units now.